# cardinality of the euclidean n-space R

Tags: cardinals

For any given $n$ determine the cardinality of the Euclidean $n$-space $$\mathbb{R}^n =
\left\{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) : x_i \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for all } i = 1, 2, \dots, n\right\}.$$ Are there ”more” points in the
Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, the Euclidean 3-space $\mathbb{R}^3$ or hyperspace $\mathbb{R}^4$ as on the real
line $\mathbb{R}$? Can anyone solve it so to understand it? I didn't understand anything.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^n$ have same cardinal number for any $n\in \Bbb N$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any natural number $n \geqslant 1$,
$$|\mathbb{R}^n|=|\mathbb{R}|=\aleph $$
where $\aleph$ denotes the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum).

**EDIT:**
A cardinality based proof is as follows
$$|\mathbb{R}^n|=|\mathbb{R}|^n=(2^{\aleph_0})^n=2^{\aleph_0 \times n}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb{R}|. $$

Comment: so the final answer is that all of them have the same cardinality because |Rn|=|R|=ℵ?

Comment: @soc No. The answer is correct but you need to justify it.

Comment: yeah but how I can justify it i got stuck with this question

Comment: @soc: see the question I linked to.

Comment: @RossMillikan so if we know the R^2-->R we know directly R^3-->R because bijective is one-to-one